# Setting system class loader for embedded JVM

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, classloader

I ama creating and embedded jvm using `CreateJavaVM` method. I also want to setup a system classsloader to be used by this jvm. However, my classes reside in memory (either received from network, or in encrypted form) so I cannot set classpath to a file system location. Instead I am thinking of setting system classloader to my custom classloader first then loading other class files using this classloader. However, I could not find a way to set system classloader to class I defined using `DefineClass` method. Setting classloader using `System.setProperty("java.system.class.loader", "org.me.CustomClassLoader")` does not work after JVM gets created.Is there a way to set the system classloader to use in memory classloader?

By the way I thought of setting classloader to java.net.URLClassloader but it is not possible because constructor signature is not matched to that expected by JVM.

```
  JavaVM *jvm;
  JNIEnv *env;
  JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; 
  JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[2];
  options[0].optionString = "-verbose:jni";
  options[1].optionString = " -Djava.system.class.loader=org.me.CustomClassLoader";
  vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
  vm_args.nOptions = 2;
  vm_args.options = options;
  vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;
  // Create jvm
  JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);

  // Read classdef from network
  jbyte *data = ReadClassDefinition();
  *jcls =env->DefineClass("org/me/CustomClassLoader", NULL, (jbyte*)data, size);
```

Answer (score 0):

I coulnd't find a way for to achieve this. I reverted to copying classloader class into a temporary jar file and giving path of this jar file as classpath parameter to JVM using `-Djava.class.path` property.